# Advertisment appears on my web browser

Tags: malware, web-browser, chrome

For 2 weeks, advertisements open themselves in my browser (In both new tab or external window).

It is really annoying and disturbing.

To solve the problem I tried using adblock, deleting all cookies and history, also blocking the websites in my local host by the command `# sudo gedit /etc/hosts`.

I attached below an screenshot about this unpleasant advertisement.

[image: Kind of ads appears themselves in my browser]

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic, however a few tips: Install MalwareBytes Anti-Malware and run a scan. You should also check your chrome extensions

Comment: You have "adware", which is a type of infection. Unfortunately we are not a malware removal site.

Comment: I don't know why in these kind of forums have rude people always putting questions in hold or replying  rude aswers. 

I just try to solve my problem on my computer. I am professional on system engineering but I just came here in order to try to find any solution for my issue.

anyway Thank you for your help

Comment: @Jonahatanpeña you asked the wrong question on the wrong site. It's not being rude to close an off-topic question. If you asked this question over at the parenting site, they would close for the same reason.

Comment: @Jonahatanpeña Maybe it helps to understand when reading the description of this site and [checking the help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help). You'll notice this is **not a forum**, but rather a Q&A (Question and Answers) website, Now, if you look at your post again, you'll notice it doesn't contain any question mark — pointing at the fact you didn't ask a single Q. That's somewhat problematic for a Q&A website. Last but not least, remember the post indeed isn't closed but merely has been put on hold. You can **edit it** and even flag/vote it to be re-opened. Hope that helps…